# Python output string with transition characters and double quotes

Tags: python

I want to output the following string n times.

```
" add x0,x0,x0      # placefold  \n\t" \
```

When I use

```
placeholder=r'" add x0,x0,x0      # placefold  \n\t" \' 
print(placeholder)
```

`EOL while scanning string literal` error occurred. I clearly added `r` in front of the string, why does this error still occur.

When i use

```
placeholder=r'" add x0,x0,x0      # placefold  \n\t" \ ' 
print(placeholder)
```

(I added a space before the`'`.)

There is no error after running. But I don’t want an extra space at the end.

what should I do?
What I want to achieve is:

```
placeholder=(r'" add x0,x0,x0      # placefold  \n\t" \' +"\n")*repeat_number
print(placeholder)
```

Thanks!

Comment: the \ at the end of string is unnessesary, thats the cause of the error

Comment: The string I want to output has a \ at the end.

Answer (score 1):

You can use string concatentation **without** the `+` operator, I suggest using this code:

```
placeholder=r'" add x0,x0,x0      # placefold  \n\t" ' '\' 
print(placeholder)
```

Notice, that `"ab"` is equal to `"a" "b"` (this works too in C).

Answer (score 1):

If you want `placeholder` to end with a backslash, consider escaping it:

```py
placeholder = r'" add x0,x0,x0      # placefold  \n\t" \\'
print(placeholder)
```

Results in: `" add x0,x0,x0      # placefold  \n\t" \\`. It looks like there are two backslashes, but there is actually only one. The console prints `\\` to notify a single backslash in this case.
Proof:

```
>>> placeholder[-1]
'\\'
```

Comment: But it ends up with double '\', which is not what the OP wants.

Comment: Incorrect. Should only end with 1 slash.

Comment: Edited my answer to prove there is actually only one backslash.

Comment: "The console prints \\ to notify a single backslash in this case. Proof," of course, because **that is the last character**, which is `\\`. Try to print the result, you got two backslashes.

Comment: Or check with `"abbb"`, there are three `b`, but if you print the `[-1]`, you will get "b".